# How to remove that annoying ammo symbol on ammo powers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is there any possible way (through a mod or direct edit) to get rid of the symbol that appears to the right of your weapon when using ammo powers?

I really like being able to switch weapon projectiles, but having a little symbol floating over my gun bothers me.

Does anybody know of a mod that removes this graphic or a way for me to do so myself?

Comment: You do realize that Ammo Powers do more than change how your ammo looks right?

Comment: Well yea rofl, I'm just anal about the feel of a character when i play it, everything has to fit. I'm just trying to find a way to get rid of that symbol. Theres allot of retexture mods out there, im sure theirs a way to make the symbol invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The symbols are there to stay--they bug me too--but there is a way around it, in a manner of speaking. Instead of automatic upgrading squadmates who have ammunition skills, you can manually go through that tree and pick that when they have a certain type of ammunition (Disruptor, Armor piercing, Incindiery, Cryo) equipped, then all squadmates including Shepard, receive the benefits of the ammunition. This results in a omni-tool tracing lining the gun colored like the ammunition type.

You only get half the effectiveness, and you can't turn it off. But hey, it gets rid of the symbols.

There's also the option of not using different ammunition types and instead using upgrade paths for modifications, weapon special abilities, and powers such as the grenades or biotics.